# PHP - INTL Extension missing

Tags: php, intl

I am using php7 in my project. I have enabled `intl` in `php.ini` file by un-comment the following line.

> ;extension=php_intl.dll

Then copied `ic*.dll` file from `php` folder to `apache/bin` folder. Also I have checked the Environment Variables.

All are correct, but still it shows error

> PHP - INTL Extension is missing.

Please help me. How can i solve this.

Answer (score 2):

**Cause:**
If you have installed the unbundled PHP version, the extension is not installed on the system. (unless you’ve installed it separately)

If you have the bundled PHP version, the extension might be existing but not enabled.

- Make sure the php_intl.dll file exists within your php extensions directory

  1. for separately installed PHP: C:\path\to\php\ext\
  2. for xampp: C:\path\to\xampp\php\ext
     (note: your drive letter might be different)
- If the file exists:

  1. Search for the config file (php.ini, usually in the same folder as the php executable) and open it
  2. Make sure the line “extension=php_intl.dll” is existing and not commented
  3. Restart the web server (usually apache)
  4. Check if the extension is enabled using phpinfo()
- If the file doesn’t exist:

  1. Check your php version by running the “php -v” command
  2. Download the PHP version that corresponds to yours from the PHP Downloads Page (TS/NTS, x86/x64)
  3. To find thread safety for php, run: php -i | findstr “Thread” , source & more info.
  4. Search for the php_intl.dll file in the ext folder in that version and copy it in your php\ext folder
  5. Repeat the steps for the case in which the file exists
     Edit: changed php7.0 occurrences with php7.x as the version may vary.

For more information about the solution, check [link](https://www.dotkernel.com/php-troubleshooting/where-is-the-intl-php-extension-problem-solved/).

Comment: php_intl.dll file exists within your php extensions directory. and it shows "Thread Safety" is enabled. Still facing the issue

Comment: which package are you using xampp, wamp ? and why is intl required

Comment: I am using Xampp

Comment: Thanks. You are the real most valuable MVP

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the `.dll` file is missing from your system.

Please check this [link](http://windows.php.net/download/) to download and install your PHP intl extension. Also do [check](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.extension-dir), whether they are pointing at the right directories.

Hope this will solve your problem.